# Android Kotlin viewBinder - change ItemView of RecyclerView Item from Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

After I switched from Kotlin Synthetics to viewBinder I can't change an itemView of a RecyclerView item from activity.

This is inside activity:

```
val viewHolder = binding.recyclerViewMemes.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as RecyclerView.ViewHolder
viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.text = "\u25CF"
```

I get `unresolved reference` on `memeCommentsCount`

This is the `ViewHolder` inside `Recyclerview`:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: MemeViewBinding?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!.root){
    val memeCommentsCount = itemView!!.memeCommentsCount
}
```

Comment: I will in case I won't be able to do it completely with viewBinder @a_local_nobody

Comment: Something is wrong with your overall design if your Activity is having to go into the adapter to modify individual ViewHolder instances. The Activity should supply changes to the individual items in the backing list and notify the adapter that that the item at that position has changed. When the activity calls `notifyItemChanged()` on the adapter, the adapter will call its own `onBindViewHolder()` for that item, so the views will be updated accordingly there. In my opinion, any use of the `findViewHolderFor...` functions is a code smell.

Comment: The way you're doing it, if the current item is off-screen, the change will not occur, and then it will be wrong when it scrolls onto the screen. And a tip in your ViewHolder class...there's no reason for `itemView` to be nullable. You're treating it as if it is not nullable anyway because you're using `!!` on it. Use of `!!` is almost always a code smell as well.

Comment: Ok I made it not nullable, there was really no point to use nullable and then !! xD Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your own implementation of `ViewHolder` but are casting your variable to the default implementation which does not have memeCommentsCount.

Instead of `as RecyclerView.ViewHolder` try `as ViewHolder` and make sure you're importing your ViewHolder class and not the default one

Alternatively rename your ViewHolder to something else like `MemeViewHolder` and cast your viewHolder variable to that

Also you are trying to get it off the itemView of the view holder when you made it a variable on the view holder itself so this line needs to change from

`viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.text = "\u25CF"`

to

`viewHolder.memeCommentsCount.text = "\u25CF"`

Comment: I tried, it automatically changed from as ViewHolder to as MemesAdapter.ViewHolder but I still have unresolved reference on memeCommentsCount

Comment: @EduardUnruh Added an update to my answer

Comment: Yes this works now. I didn't need to rename ViewHolder since I imported my custom one anyway, using viewHolder.memeCommentsCount.text instead of viewHolder.itemView.memeCommentsCount.text the only thing that was still missing. Thanks!!